# Simple and effective solution for combining Java, Python, PyTables and HDF5

Tags: java, python, jython, hdf5, pytables

I'm a newbie in Python, PyTables and HDF5. I'm looking for simple and best solution for my problem.

Problem is next. On one side I have many XML files with data. I just wanna parse these files and put data in hdf5 file on other side. Later, I will use this data trough some search criteria.Why HDF5? Because need to put large dataset and because speed. Using RDBMS will make problems with performance during JOIN operations. Solution must provide speed and good memory performance.

After some googling I find Python and PyTables as possible solution. My idea is parse data from XML in Java (this code must be writen in Java), after that write python script which insert data in hdf5 using PyTables API and executing python script from Java. So, I'm writing and executing python script from Java program. For writing python script in Java I'm using java.io.* package and for executing Process class in Java. For example:

> p.exec("cmd /c C:\MyScripts\myscript.py")

I don't know is this solution good. For me is not cool writing scripts from Java using java.io.*. Probably, I will have problems later with reading results from scripts ( when I make some search criteria using Python scripts and PyTables API).

So, I have few questions about my problem. What is the best solution between parsing XML data on one side and store data in hdf5 on other side? Am I on right way with this solution (writing and executing python scripts from Java code)? What about Python and PyTables? Are these technologies good solution for my problem? Also I read couple things about Jython, but I don't know is it possible combine it with PyTables?

Opinion and tips from professionals are welcome. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Out of vague curosity, why must the XML code be written in Java?  Python has plenty of excellent xml parsing/writing libraries.  If you really want to use PyTables, it would seem easier to move everything to python...

Comment: Yes, you alright. I didn't think about that because don't have much experience with python. Also, I'm working on small part of a big project and I'm not sure about that I have permission to use python for parsing, but I think that not would be a problem. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3):

> For me is not cool writing scripts from Java using `java.io.*`.

Same here -- you have already parsed the data from the XML into some internal representation in Java, and then you re-write this data into a Python script, and then the Python interpreter will re-parse the data into an internal representation for writing to the HDF5 files. It couples together both the Java XML parsing interface, the XML data format, and the Python APIs for manipulating HDF5 files, which sounds like more moving parts than there ought to be. (Do you *really* want to break out `javac` just to update a renamed Python package?)

I think it'd be worth taking another step backwards and look at the two steps of the problem:

- parse XML
- write HDF5

There's no reason why there should be two languages between those -- I'd stick entirely with Java or entirely with Python. The end result will run faster in less memory on more systems and be more maintainable regardless of which language you choose.

Comment: Like I mentioned before, I don't have experience with HDF5. Maybe is better solution use some JAVA API for HDF5 instead of PyTables, but I don't know is it provide same performance as using Python and PyTables. Note that I will make in the future a lot of queries with data in HDF5 and I need speed for that. So, Java API for HDF5 or PyTables? What is better solution? Or something else?

Comment: Once your data is converted into HDF5 using whatever tool is most convenient for you to write, feel free to write _queries_ using whatever language is most convenient. You could write the importer entirely in Java and the queries entirely in Python, or the other way around -- combining the two into a single program that builds scripts that do the other half of the work is what really concerned me as highly unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a project were I parsed around 60 000 Python cPickle files and put the contents (matrix of approx. 31k rows and 4 columns) into separate PyTables tables. 
It works and perform really well.

But I agree with sarnold. I would either stick to java or python, whatever you have most experience and are most comfortable with. I do think that it's easier to get results with python and pytables, especially when writing import scripts.

BTW what is the reason why you want to run python scripts from java?  Why not run the python script directly?

BTW there is also the python [h5py](http://alfven.org/wp/hdf5-for-python/) package which is more low level than PyTables.   PyTables actually builds up an additional abstraction layer on top of HDF5. For example PyTables has the concept of tables which is similar to tables in an RDBMS and supports indexes (both not supported by HDF5 out of the box)

Theoretically you can read a HDF5 files that are created with PyTables from Java. However you don't get out of the box support for all the PyTable features like tables and indexes.
In addition to this if you use the [Blosc](http://blosc.pytables.org/trac) compression algorithm in PyTables you might not be able to load it in Java at all.

Comment: The process for writing must be automatic, when I parse xml files with Java I must run script for insert data in hdf5. Maybe is better solution parse XML files with python and exclude Java from all process? I decide use Java for parsing XML, because I don't know python well, but is not a problem I will figure out. Otherwise, when I read data I will make a lot of different queries. My plan is to use data from hdf5 for some analysis. Yesterday I read about Java HDF5 API but I'm not satisfied with features. PyTables provide easy and nice API for exploring and searching data. Also more quickly.

Comment: I would recommend to use python and pytables then. It's really super easy to write a parser for XML in python and the API of pytables is really convenient. For example you can use ipython together with pytables which gives you code completion and allows you to navigate through the hdf5 without any effort. If you make queries make sure you use pytables 2.3 because it supports creating of indexes which improvies performance of the queries by a fair amount. Also if you have huge data make sure to use compression (preferable blosc) which  can improve performance futher

Comment: I will consider that. Thanks for advice.